# HTML <select option selected="selected"> won't work with PHP function

Tags: php, html, function, html-select

I want to display a  tag with a selected option, which would come from a database.
This is my code:

```
<?
function check($opt) {
    if ($rows['fa'] = $opt) {
        echo " selected='selected'";
    }
}
echo $fa;
?>

<select name="opt" id="opt">
    <option value="o1"<? check('o1'); ?>>Option1</option>
    <option value="o2"<? check('o2'); ?>>Option2</option>
</select>
```

The problem is that the function doesn't work with $rows['$fa'], and it works if I just type either "o1", or "o2". 
If I echo $fa, it gives me the result ("o1", or"o2") from the database.

Comment: Where do you define `$rows` ?

Comment: $sql="SELECT * FROM table WHERE id='$id'";
    $result=mysql_query($sql);
    $rows= mysql_fetch_assoc($result);

Comment: I think you should check this: http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If the data of row is on $fa, set as global, please attention to the scope, the comparison (==):

```
<?
function check($opt) {
   global $fa;
   if ($fa == $opt) {
      echo " selected='selected'";
   }
}
echo $fa;
?>
```

Comment: Cool, it works! Using global, I don't need to define all the variables in the function. Awesome, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

(Assuming `$rows` was defined already).

You are using `=` to compare variables, which won't work. `=` assigns. You are looking for `==`:

```
function check($opt) {
  if ($rows['fa'] == $opt) {
    echo " selected='selected'";
  }
}
```

Also, try using `$fa` instead of `'fa'` in your array index. I'm not sure if this is what you are referring to:

```
function check($opt) {
  if ($rows[$fa] == $opt) {
    echo " selected='selected'";
  }
}
```

Comment: What is `$fa`? Where is it defined?

Comment: I have defined $rows, but outside the function, that's why it didn't work. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

`$rows['fa']` is defined outside of the function, which is no value in the function scope

Other changes:-

```
selected('o1', $row['fa']);

function selected($opt, $val)
{
  if ($opt == $val)
  {
    echo " selected='selected'";
  }
}
```

Comment: I dared to edit your code to make it more generic. I  doubt it makes any sense in such a localized version it was.

Comment: I don't like to be boss :) I just can't make myself stop thinking. I just took the OP's place and realized that I can make use of such a template helper but of course if it's going to be a generic one, common for all the codes.

Comment: Is true, but i don't think OP are using any sort of framework, or too lazy to build such functions for form elements (don't we deal with form submission everyday?)

Comment: That was it, $rows['fa'] was defined outside of the function. Now it works! Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

```
<select name="opt" id="opt"> 
<option value="o1"<? if($rows['fa'] == 'o1') ?> selected='selected'<? endif ?>>Option1</option> 
<option value="o2"<? if($rows['fa'] == 'o2') ?> selected='selected'<? endif ?>>Option2</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This does work, and works well. It's just a bit too much code if I have more options.

Comment: if you have more options you have to call this code only once, because it should be printed via loop from array